# insertRecord not saving values in new row

Tags: c++, qt

It inserts record but without the provided values. [I have tried it with 02 version of Qt]

```
// contentModel is the subclass of QSqlTableModel
bool contentModel::addRecord () {

QSqlRecord newRecord = this->record();
newRecord.setValue("id", 3); 
newRecord.setValue("data", "chilling humanity");
newRecord.setValue("type", "text");
qDebug() << "field" << newRecord.value(1);   // output: chilling humanity

if(this->insertRecord(-1,newRecord)) {  // new row is the third row
      qDebug() << "data => " << this->data(index(2, 1), 258);    // output: empty string

  }
}

QVariant contentModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
QVariant value;

if (index.isValid()) {
    if (role < Qt::UserRole) {
        value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
    } else {
        int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
        value = QSqlTableModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }
}
return value;
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> contentModel::roleNames() const {

QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 1, "model_id");
roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 2, "model_data");
roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 3, "model_type");

return roles;
}
```

Comment: What are the column names of the table you are trying to alter?

Comment: @Botje (id, data, type)

Comment: @MuhmmmadBilal call `select();`

Comment: Mysteriously, insertRecord is not working but insertRows is doing fine. It served the purpose!!!